# Badge images "too large"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges

This is only a recent development. However, it seems like the badge images displayed on the [Badges page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges) is a little too large for the frame they're in:

[image: Badge images too large] [image: Badge images OK]

On the left is the view through Internet Explorer (8.0.7601.17514 64-bit) & Chrome (16.0.912.75 m); Firefox (9.0.1) is on the right.

Comment: Confirmed also on Chrome 17.0.963.38, but not present in IE 9.0.9112.16421

Comment: Confirmed in Safari 5.1.2, but not in IE 9.0.8112.16421 (both Win 7).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up, this will be fixed in the next build.  We're consolidating some stray inline `<style>` blocks (Jin just *loves* those) from various pages into their correct stylesheets which caused a few hiccups like this.